# Star Trek books about the Federation outside of Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, novel, novella

Are there any Star Trek novels that depict the Federation primarily or entirely outside of Starfleet? There’s been a lot of fan speculation over the years on what civilian life in the Federation would be like, and I’d like to see whether any writers have actually tackled the subject.

Comment: The first two chapters of The Autobiography of James T. Kirk are accounts before he joined Starfleet, both living on Earth and a Federation Colony.

Comment: I don't see this as a list / recommendations question because it's asking if such a thing has been depicted. That seems on topic to me

Comment: @NKCampbell - Feels listy to me; *What are all the books that have X?*

Comment: This might be a case where we don't know until it's answered if the answer is "no", or a small bounded list, both of which would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at the [Novels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Novels) page of Memory Alpha, I found two novels that seems to fit:

- [Articles of the Federation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Articles_of_the_Federation_(novel)), which deals with the political side of the Federation,
- [New Worlds, New Civilizations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/New_Worlds,_New_Civilizations), follows a journalist exploring iconic locations, meeting some well known figures and being present at a some historical events.